# Segmentation Fault when wrapping V8 in a class?

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I want to use Google's Javascript Engine [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) in a project, and attempted to write a wrapper class for the engine. Parts of the Code are copied from samples/shell.cc, from the V8 Distribution.

However, it just aborts with a Segmentation fault, and I can't figure out why, although the problem is happening around `v8::internal::Top::global_context()` (due to an invalid `context`, which appears to be NULL).. The code itself looks fine to me, but maybe I did something incredibly stupid :-).

The Segmentation fault in my Code happens in `v8::Script::Compile`.

Code in Question (Updated): https://gist.github.com/4c28227185a14bb6288c

Thanks to [Luis G. Costantini R.'s Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252552/segmentation-fault-when-wrapping-v8-in-a-class/4288970#4288970), there is no longer a problem in `Set` (It doesn't abort anymore), however, exposed names are still not available and will result in a ReferenceError...

Comment: See if you could investigate the status of variables and registers in the stack frames.  That could give some more clue.

Comment: It never goes further than `v8::Script::Compile`, and I've already checked the context, which is valid.

Comment: "global context" seems to imply that you've forgotten some global initialization call (which might perhaps be performed by instantiating some object of some special V8 class, or just an ordinary function call). sorry i haven't used V8. but check that.

Comment: The actual global context is initiated in `JavaScript::JavaScript`, though I believe that the error occurs, because v8 is using global variables internally... which would explain the Segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thy to change v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context); from the constructor (line 134) to internal_executeString (before script = v8::Script::Compile(source, name);).  That because the destructor of the class v8::Context::Scope exits from the context.

I changed the method addFunction:

```
void addFunction(const std::string& fname, v8::InvocationCallback func)
{
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope;
    std::cout << "before ::Set()" << std::endl;
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
    context->Global()->Set(v8::String::New(fname.c_str()),
                           v8::FunctionTemplate::New(func)->GetFunction());
    std::cout << "after ::Set()" << std::endl;
}
```

The function must be added to the global object of the context used to execute the script.  There is an excellent tutorial (in two parts) of V8:
http://www.homepluspower.info/2010/06/v8-javascript-engine-tutorial-part-1.html
 and 
http://www.homepluspower.info/2010/06/v8-javascript-engine-tutorial-part-2.html

Comment: I don't see how that would help, to be honest. The ctor isn't supposed to call `internal_executeString` at all.

Comment: Yes, but you are declaring v8::Context::Scope inside the constructor, no inside internal_executeString.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now. That took care of the segmentation fault in `Compile()`, however, the global context is now aborting when I try to expose a global name, via `global->Set(...)`. I've updated my question.

Comment: I think that you must create the global:
global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(); before create the context: context = v8::Context::New(NULL, global);

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change that line. No change, unfortunately. See updated question.

Comment: In method addFunction I think you do not need v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context); Before Set the function, because as I understood that is necessary only to switch context of execution; and may be that is causing the problem.

Comment: Well, that took care of the segmentation fault in Set, but the print function is still not exposed. I'm putting my faith into you now, because I'm really about to give up on v8 :-)

Comment: Aaaand 50+ Reputation to you :-) Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to create an instance of JavaScript Function (FunctionTemplate::GetFunction()) or JavaScript Object (ObjectTemplate::NewInstance()) before entering the context (via Context::Scope), you get the segmentation fault. The reason: there is no JavaScript context available and both Function and Object always exist in a JavaScript execution context only. As per V8 documentation:

**Function**:
A JavaScript function object (ECMA-262, 15.3).

**Object**:
A JavaScript object (ECMA-262, 4.3.3).

Comment: Not really an answer to the question.  How does this improve the already accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

The stack backtrace is almost useless unless I download all the source and try to build it myself, so... :)

Change `js.executeString("1+1", true, false);` to `js.executeString("1+1", true, true);` and see what the exception handler tells you?

Comment: No change, still aborts with a Segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just got stung by [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=173&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20HW%20OS%20Area%20Stars), that is if you have not already taken note of it.  Perhaps submit another report since the referenced one looks old.  Perhaps dig a little deeper and investigate the stack frame at every function call until the Segmentation Fault is received, you could either find a work around or the fix for this bug :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar segmentation fault and the problem turned out to be the following.  I was creating a new thread and attempting to create an object template and object in that thread.  Unfortunately it seems that if you create a thread, you need to make sure that you enter a v8::Context again in order to do such things.

I got it working by passing a Handle to the v8::Context::Calling to the newly created thread and entered it in the new thread by using a scope.

I wrote this here as it is the only useful thing that comes up when I do a google search for the segmentation fault.